# fetching data from api in react-native snap carousel but not working properly

Tags: api, react-native, redux, carousel, react-snap

I am using your react-native Snap carousel, It works great, But I am trying to get data from API, It worked but It shows me total data in one card. How can i show it separately?

**Here is the code:**

**List.js**

```
mainExample () {
        const { slider1ActiveSlide } = this.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <Carousel
                    data={data}
                />
                <Pagination
                    dotsLength={length}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

**SliderEntry.js**

```
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={1}
                onPress={() => { alert(`You've clicked`); }}
            >
                <View>
                    {Title}
                    <Text
                    >
                        {available}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
```

It's showing all fetched data in one card. Anyone Please help me!

Comment: hie brother! please share the api response

Comment: may i show you console data ?

Comment: yeah that would be great

Comment: please check my updated code brother

Comment: can you tell what is the expected out put! any screen shot! or UX ?

Comment: It's showing all the data in one card. As you can see in screenshot i have given in question, I want it show separately in each card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with the plugin itself.

Since you're already passing `responseMsg._embedded.items` to the `Carousel`, you should just leverage the prop `data` of your `SliderEntry` component instead of referencing it again and mapping it.

```
const { name, available } = data;

return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{ name }</Text>
        <Text>{ available }</Text>
    </<TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data